# Prove that the complement of a disc in the complex plane is connected

Tags: complex-analysis

How do you rigorously prove that the complement of an open or closed disc in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ is connected?

Comment: It should be fairly easy to show it is path connected, which then implies it is connected.

Comment: I could visualize that the complement is path-connected, but I'm not sure what the continuous curve that connects any two points in the complement should strictly be.

Comment: @AndrewYuan the first curve that comes to mind is the following: if you have a point $a$ with $\left|a\right| = r$, then you should be able to define a path from $a$ to the unique intersection point of the n-sphere of radius $r$ and the ray from $0$ to $b$, and then you can continue the path from _that_ point thence to $b$. Does that help?

Comment: And such a path is guaranteed to have every point at least as far from the origin as $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Ahhh, I see now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If $z_j = r_je^{i\varphi_j}$, $j=1,2$, are in the complement of the disc, then $z(t) = r(t)e^{i\varphi(t)}$ is such a path, where $r(t) = tr_1 + (1-t)r_2$, $\varphi(t) = t\varphi_1 + (1-t)\varphi_2$, $t\in [0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

It's the continuous image of a connected set, and is therefore connected. For example, let $E = \{(x,y): x^2 + y^2 > 1\}.$ Define $f : (1,\infty)\times [0,2\pi] \to E$ by setting $f(r, t) = (r\cos t, r\sin t).$ Then $f$ is surjective. Since $f$ is continuous and $(1,\infty)\times [0,2\pi]$ is connected (it's convex for example), $f((1,\infty)\times [0,2\pi])=E$ is connected.

Comment: And how do you show that $(1,\infty)\times [0,2\pi]$ is connected?

Comment: It's convex $\,$.

Comment: And how do you prove that a convex set is connected? I mean it was already shown in the comments that $E$ is path-connected. I understood that you reduced the problem to a simpler set which is easier seen to be connected (without using path-connectedness).

Comment: The path connectedness for a convex set is much simpler, and this is a different way to see the answer.

Comment: ;-) Alright....